# How do I stop a leaking tub faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, leak

This tub faucet (that is probably 20+ years old) has a pretty steady drip going and I'm not sure where to start to figuring out how to stop it.

[image: Photo of faucet]

(apologies for the grainy photo...just had my the camera on my phone with me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several possibilities for the cause of the leak -- incorrect valve placement, a worn washer, a worn valve.  All of them will require you to remove the valve stem to investigate.  You'll need:

- a plumbing valve wrench -- I have a set like this:

[image: valve wrench set]

- Teflon plumber's tape.
- possibly some replacement washers (but you won't know until you've removed the valve stem).
- possibly even a replacement valve stem.

Searching for some information, I came across [this article](http://www.acehardware.com/info/index.jsp?categoryId=1280424) that describes the repair process very well.

Comment: Right on.  After 20 years those old washers gotta be tired. Don't be surprised if the valve stem is difficult to remove. Don't forget to turn off the hot and cold water sources first!

Comment: Is that a "cartridge type" faucet in the link you mention @Niall C.?  I think that's what it would be if you pull it out to adjust the flow and turn for hot/cold.  If you swivel the handle up for flow I think it's a ball-type.